# HashRouter navigation adding a #

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use HashRouter in my project, but it is not working. I have a Navigation folder where I manage my application navigation:

```
import React from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './Home';
import Test from './Test';

function Navigation() {
   return (
      <Router>
         <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
            <Route path="/test" exact={true} component={Test} />
         </Switch>
      </Router>
   )
}

export default Navigation;
```

My App.js only calls the Navigation folder:

```
import React from "react";

import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";

function App() {
  return (
      <>
        <Navigation />
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then, in the Home component, I have an href to open the Test page.

```
...

const headerSelect = (value) => {
   localStorage.setItem("page", value);
}
...

<a onclick={() => headerSelect("test")} href="/test">
   TEST
</a>
...
```

When I run the application, it loads as: http://localhost:3000/#/
Then, when I click on TEST, it does not go to the test page, still in the home page, and the URL shows: http://localhost:3000/test#/

If I manually change the URL to http://localhost:3000/#/test it works. How can I fix the route or href to make it work properly? Also, is it possible to get rid of the '#' in the URLs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's me again.

Try using Link in react-router-dom if you're using anchor tags.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to="/benefits">Benefits<Link>
```

To further answer your question: you could use Gatsby.js and Netlify to serve your app statically and avoid using HashRouter.

Comment: Thank you again. The Link works, but I have a ```$(document).ready(function() {``` that needs to be called for every page that I load (It's just one .js file being imported in the index.html). After changing the ```<a href>``` to ```<Link>```, the ```$(document).ready(function() {``` stop being called.

Comment: And you are right. I tested in Netlify and it worked, so my server provider can't serve the app. Can I create a NodeJS application to load my React website?